# Disable GTK Widget signals and callback function

Tags: python, gtk, signals

I have an `Gtk.ComboBox` which calls a function on `changed`. This helps me figuring out if the user selected something from the dropdown (trigger a loading function) or types something in (don't trigger a loading function) Now when I update/refresh the combobox entries which are available, the combobox signals `changed` gets triggered really often. So my idea was to disable its signals, update the combobox entries, enable signals again. How can I achieve this in Python 3, GTK 3? I'm also using Glade because I have a big amount of signals, so I don't want to connect them manually if possible.

Comment: What is the problem, before ***"when I update/refresh"***, to disable `on_changed` and reconnect it afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore any `None` values when retrieving `combo.get_active_id()`

Then hook up to the `changed` signal of the internal entry of the combo to see what the user changes in the entry